# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

Ayuda porfa
Necesito implementar try catch en este código y para este error, como podría
implementarlo si me sale este error al tratar de obtener la lista sin haber generado nada antes.

Quiero arreglar ese error...
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
at RandomGen.getList(RandomGen.java:49)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RandomGen {
     int parameter;
     int sizeList;
     long t1=0;
     long t2=0;
     ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers= new ArrayList<>();
     public RandomGen(int parameter, int size){
        this.parameter = parameter; 
        sizeList = size;
     }
     //GENERA EL NUMERO ALEATORIO DENTRO DEL PARAMETRO
    private int numberGen()
     {
         Random rand = new Random();
         return rand.nextInt(parameter);
         //(int)(Math.random()*parameter);
     }
     //GENERA LISTA DE NUMEROS ALEATORIOS 
     public void genListRep(){
         t1 = System.nanoTime();
         for(int i = 0; i<sizeList; i++){
             myNumbers.add(numberGen());
         }
         t2 = System.nanoTime();
         System.out.println("Parametro: "+ parameter+ "\n Tamaño Lista: "+sizeList+ "\nTiempo con rep: "+(t2-t1));
     }
     //GENERA NUMEROS ALEATORIOS SIN REPETIR
        public void genListNoRep(){
         t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         for(int i = 0; i<sizeList; i++){
             myNumbers.add(numberGen());             
         }
         
         for(int i = 0; i< sizeList-1; i++){
             for(int j = 1; j<sizeList; j++){
                 if(myNumbers.get(i)== myNumbers.get(j)){
                     myNumbers.set(i, numberGen());  
                     
                 }
             }
         }
         t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println("Parametro: "+ parameter+ "\n Tamaño Lista: "+sizeList+ "\nTiempo sin rep: "+(t2-t1));
     }
    //OBTIENE LA LISTA DE TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS DENTRO DEL ARREGLO
    public void getList(){
         for(int i= 0; i<sizeList; i++){
             System.out.println(myNumbers.get(i));
         }
     }
        
    public void getNumberOfElements(int n){
         for(int i= 0; i<n; i++){
             System.out.println(myNumbers.get(i));
         }
     }
     
        public boolean listNoRepCheck(){
        boolean rep= false;
         for(int i = 0; i < sizeList-1; i++){
             for(int j = 1; j < sizeList; j++){
                 if(myNumbers.get(i)== myNumbers.get(j+1)){
                     rep = true;
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return rep;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Cual es el método que llamas de tu Clase RandomGen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre que utilices un `for` para recorrer las posiciones de un `ArrayList` este debe haberse llenado antes.

recomiendo que siempre que quieras ver el contenido de una lista, lo realices utilizando el `size()` de esta manera te aseguras de recorrer basado en la cantidad de elementos que tiene tu lista.

```
public void getList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(myNumbers.get(i));
    }
}
```

La razón por la que te causa error es por que intentas ejecutar el método `getList()` antes de que tu arreglo contenga elementos, la mejor forma de solucionarlo sería como el código anterior.

### Otras soluciones que te pueden ayudar

Utilizando `if` en tu método `getList()`.

```
public void getList() {
    if (myNumbers.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println(
                "Ejecute cualquiera de los siguientes metodos antes"
                +"\ngenListRep"
                +"\ngenListNoRep"
        );
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeList; i++) {
        System.out.println(myNumbers.get(i));
    }
}
```

Ejecutar `genListRep()` o `genListNoRep()` dentro de `getList()`.

```
public void getList() {
    genListRep();
    genListNoRep();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeList; i++) {
        System.out.println(myNumbers.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el foreach para recorrer listas, solo corrige eso ;)

```
public void getList(){
    
   for (Integer num : myNumbers) {            
       System.out.println(num);         
   }
}
```

Luego en el main haz esta llamada:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomGen r = new RandomGen(10, 5);
    r.genListRep();
    r.getList();
```

}